# How to pass a restricted scope to a widget in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the scope of my main controller as :

```
$scope.names=[];
$scope.articles=[];
$scope.whatever=[];
```

I want to have a Directive/Controller that should only list "names" (and I don't want it to be able to access others).
Can I, and if yes how to, create and link this scope (restricted to names array) to this Directive/Controller?

Comment: Depending on what exactly you want to do and in anticipation of Angular2 it might be worth looking into Angular 1.5 components. They give you the ability to do one-way binding which might help with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a directive called names and pass this to the isolated scope of directive.

```
<Names names="names"></Names>
```

And then in your directive, you can access it like this.

```
angular.module("yourapp").directive('Names', function(){
        return {
             scope : { names :"=" }
        }    
});
```

Comment: Simple but still effective, thank you. I will try right now and come back to you.

Comment: And just for my knowledge and perhaps for other persons, would it be possible to do the same for a Controller (instead of a Directive)?

Comment: Directives are components which you can re-use in multiple places, you can do the same in controller depending upon your need... you could pass the names array to your view which has a ng-repeat and it could list only the names you want with a custom filter...